# How to post form-data containing arrays and objects using angular to node server

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am sending formData containing data and file togehter, using angularJs to node server.

- When I am posting data with `productName,description,car,fileNames`, then I am able to post data to database.
- When I am sending data with `productName,description,car,fileNames` along with `productStock`, then node server is throwing exception,

  > Image validation failed: productStock: Cast to Array failed for value "[object Object]" at path "productStock"
- And when I am sendin data from angular, without using formdata, then everything is getting saved successfully.

**Model**

```
var mongoose=require('mongoose');
var Schema=mongoose.Schema;

    var imageSchema=new Schema({
        productName:{type: String, require: false},
        description:{type: String,required: false},
        car:{type: String,required: false},
        imagePaths: [{type: String,required: false}],
        productStock: [
        {
            size: {type: Number, required: false},
            quantity: {type: Number, required: false}

        }
        ]
    });
```

**Angular controller:**

```
var formData = new FormData();
                for(key in $scope.product){
                  formData.append(key, $scope.product[key]);
                  console.log('FormData:' + $scope.product[key])
                }
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/image/upload',formData,{
                  transformRequest: angular.identity,
                  headers:{
                            'Content-Type': undefined
                  }
                }).then(function(res){

                });
```

*Console.log output on angular controller:*

```
FormData:[object Object] // `productStock` data showing as [object object]
FormData:saab
FormData:iii
```

Why this is happening, please help.

Comment: it appears that `productStock` is defined as an array;  are you passing an array of objects from the formData?

Comment: I don't know, I mean, my intention is to pass formData with files, objects and array. `productStock` is an array.

Comment: why I am getting problem with `productStock` only, when I am sending data without using `formData`, then everything is getting saved at the server.

Comment: that's impossible to answer without seeing the contents of `formData`.  can you [edit] the question and post the result of that `console.log` call?

Comment: I have updated the question with `console.log` output.

Comment: Well that's not helpful;  that doesn't identify what that data is supposed to match with at all.  Also, why are you trying to manually deserialize `$scope.product` instead of just passing `$scope.product` directly in the post and letting angular deserialize it for you automatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159794/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-claies).

Comment: you can't append an object to FormData, you would have to deserialize each key in the object.  FormData only accepts `string` or `blob`, not `array`, `object`, etc...  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: Oh okay got it, so how can I send my array data using formData?

Comment: here is a post (not written by me, but a good reference) with a factory that can transform a complex object to formData:  https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2615-posting-form-data-with-http-in-angularjs.htm